# Spring Controller info

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets, controller

Do this two methods of a @Controller the same thing?In what they differ?
This is a Spring mvc example with a form. The first method adds an object to the model or not ??Thanks

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Member form() { 
  return new Member();
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void form() { 
 model.addAttribute(new Member());

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code wont compile, but if you change it to for example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView form(ModelAndView model) { 
model.addObject("member", new Member());
model.setViewName("view");
return model
```

}

it will try to return view.html ( that depends how do you configure ViewResolver ), and Member object will be available under name "member"

for template library like Freemarker  - so you can print something from it to user.

First method can be used for example for REST api, so you return member to anyone who calls your HomeController.

Comment: This is an example.I want to know if the first method add the Member item to the model

Comment: no, it just returns it - for example in json form if you add @ResponseBody.

Comment: I found this first method in a book and it says that "Serves empty form"..What does this mean?